# FreeSWITCH originate_timeout timer

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch

Does the originate_timeout start as soon as the invite is sent?  If we get a 180 ringing 6 seconds in, does it restart?  How is post dial delay (PDD) handled in this case? Does that have to be added into the originate_timeout seconds?

We have some carriers that take several seconds (up to 10-12) to actually come back with a cause code, if we fail over to a new carrier it can mess things up if we get back a 503 10 seconds into a 20 second origination_timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`originate_timeout` looks for early media `183` or actual answer `200` ok
to stop countdown.

if you have set `ignore_early_media=true` before bridge, then originate_timeout will count seconds until it gets `200` ok if not it will drop the call.

try `bridge_answer_timeout` which looks only for `200` ok